# Data Frame containing hyphens using R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I have created a list (Based on items in a column) in order to subset my dataset into smaller datasets relating to a particular variable. This list contains strings with hyphens in them `-`.

```
dim.list <- c('Age_CareContactDate-Gender', 'Age_CareContactDate-Group',
         'Age_ServiceReferralReceivedDate-Gender',
         'Age_ServiceReferralReceivedDate-Gender-0-18',
         'Age_ServiceReferralReceivedDate-Group',
         'Age_ServiceReferralReceivedDate-Group-ReferralReason')
```

I have then written some code to loop through each item in this list subsetting my main data.

```
for (i in dim.list) {assign(paste("df1.",i,sep=""),df[df$Dimension==i,])}
```

This works fine, however when I come to aggregate this in order to get some summary statistics I can't reference the dataset as `R` stops reading after the hyphen (I assume that the hyphen is some special character)

If I use a different list without hyphens e.g.

```
dim.list.abr <- c('ACCD_Gen','ACCD_Grp',
              'ASRRD_Gen',
              'ASRRD_Gen_0_18',
              'ASRRD_Grp',
              'ASRRD_Grp_RefRsn')
```

When my for loop above executes I get 6 `data.frames` with no observations.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How about just using `split(df, df$Dimension)`?

Comment: Hyphens aren't allowed in standard variable names. Think of a simple example: `a-b`. Is it a variable name with a hyphen or is it a minus b? The R interpreter assumes a minus b, because it doesn't require spaces for binary operations. You can force non-standard names to work using backticks, `\`a-b\` <- 5` or `\`x+y\` <- 10`, but you're better off following the rules and using standard names without special characters like `+ - * / % $ # @ ! & | ^` in them.

Comment: Gregor is exactly correct. But you likely are much better off by putting your subsetted data.frames in a list, instead of assigning them all separately. This is why I suggest using `split` (which would save you quite a lot of coding too!).

Comment: And, I completely agree with Axeman. Use `split` to divide up your data frame into a list. And keep it in a list rather than use `assign`, it will be much easier to loop over or use `lapply` with that way. You might want to read my answer at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for a lot of discussion and examples.

Comment: @Axeman I played around with split but it wasn't really what i wanted, i was aiming for 6 separate datasets rather than a list of datasets. Besides dim.list is not the complete set of unique entries in the Dimensions column.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks both, sorry to be a pain but can either of you explain the advantage of using a list of datasets rather then 6 individual ones? At least from a ease of use point of view it seems difficult to view the individual datasets when in list form

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(dim.list)) {assign(paste("df1.",i,sep=""),df[df$Dimension==dimlist[i],])}` should work. But I still advise using lists. Viewing is easy, with `list[[1]]` etc. Using lists reduces the number of objects, make it easy to change your list of variables later, and allows you to `lapply` over all subsets easily.

Comment: Read my [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) answer. It's the best sell I can do on the benefits of using lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment to answer:

Hyphens aren't allowed in standard variable names. Think of a simple example: `a-b`. Is it a variable name with a hyphen or is it a minus b? The R interpreter assumes a minus b, because it doesn't require spaces for binary operations. You can force non-standard names to work using backticks, e.g.,

```
# terribly confusing names:
`a-b` <- 5
`x+y` <- 10
`mean(x^2)` <- "this is awful"
```

but you're better off following the rules and using standard names without special characters like `+ - * / % $ # @ ! & | ^ ( [ ' "` in them. At `?quotes` there is a section on *Names and Identifiers*:

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.) and the underscore. They must not start with a digit nor underscore, nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid identifiers.

So that's *why* you're getting an error, but what you're doing isn't good practice. I completely agree with Axeman's comments. Use `split` to divide up your data frame into a list. And keep it in a list rather than use `assign`, it will be much easier to loop over or use `lapply` with that way. You might want to read my answer at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for a lot of discussion and examples.

Regarding your comment *"`dim.list` is not the complete set of unique entries in the Dimensions column"*, that just means you need to subset before you split:

```
nice_list = df[df$Dimension %in% dim.list, ]
nice_list = split(nice_list, nice_list$Dimension)
```

Comment: Ok thanks (@Axeman as well), probably not the answer i wanted but it helps - will go back and rewrite this using split and see if i can get this to work!

Comment: If you want to continue with your method, you just need to replace all the hyphens with underscores first. But lists are not *that* hard and learning to use them well will make you a much more effective R programmer. (corrected typo! First version of this comment said "lists are *that* hard"! Completely the opposite!)