# Error when doing Panel VAR (panelvar package) in R

Tags: r, panel-data, multivariate-time-series, vector-auto-regression

I tried to run a panel var on dataset I got from Statistics Sweden and here is what I get:

```
df<- read_excel("Inkfördelning per kommun.xlsx")
nujavlar <- pvarfeols(dependent_vars = c("Kvintil-1", "Kvintil-4", "Kvintil-5"),
lags = 1,
transformation = "demean",
data = df,
panel_identifier = c("Kommun", "Year")
)
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Kvintil-1` doesn't exist.
```

I often get this message too:

```
Warning in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Location 2 doesn't exist.
ℹ There are only 1 column.
```

I have made sure that all data is numeric. I have also tried cleaning my workspace and restarted the programme. I also tried to convert it into a paneldata frame with palm package. I also tried converting my entity variable "Kommun" (Municipality) into factors and it still doesn't work.
Here's the data if someone wants to give it a go.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Ak_Z2n6my-5wEw69G29_NLryQKcrYZC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113164216369677216623&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

The column names in your dataframe are `Kvintil 1`, not `Kvintil-1`, so the variable you are referring to really does not exist. Please be aware that in R, [variable names cannot have hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48811387/14992857) and it is good practice to avoid spaces in variable names [because it is annoying to refer to variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554977/14992857). I have included a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gsheet)
library(panelvar)
url <- 'docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Ak_Z2n6my-5wEw69G29_NLryQKcrYZC'
df <- gsheet2tbl(url) %>%
  rename(Kvintil1 = `Kvintil 1`) %>%
  rename(Kvintil2 = `Kvintil 2`) %>%
  rename(Kvintil3 = `Kvintil 3`) %>%
  rename(Kvintil4 = `Kvintil 4`) %>%
  rename(Kvintil5 = `Kvintil 5`) %>%
  as.data.frame()
 
nujavlar <- pvarfeols(                      
  dependent_vars = c("Kvintil1", "Kvintil4", "Kvintil5"),
  lags = 1,
  transformation = "demean",
  data = df,
  panel_identifier = c("Kommun", "Year"))
```